# Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘fs’

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Below are the two error (image) I’m facing
I’m using Ionic 4.
everything works but as soon I start calling WooCommerce API and use it in constructor I get the below two errors.

I have imported Woocommerce API, but when I initialize it in constructr it shows [image]both of this error.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) which has an obsolete warning:

> - 2019-07-29: This client is obsolete and will no longer receive updates, a new JavaScript library is available under the name of @woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api.

However, that's a node.js package. It's failing because `fs` stands for filesystem and that doesn't exist in the browser.

Node.js is for local development, not for browser packages, which is what Ionic 4 is built with.

However, if you really want to use it then this guide will show you how to wrap it up using browserify:

> ## Transforming a Node.js Module to A Browser Library
>
> The solution is to use Browserify to bundle the module with all its dependencies inside one JavaScript file so we will not need any external Node.js dependencies which are not available inside the Cordova webview (a headless browser) used by Ionic 4.

https://www.techiediaries.com/woocommerce-ionic-2/

I don't know how far you'll get as it's for Ionic 2 but I'm just showing you this to demonstrate that node.js packages are not for Ionic.

## Update

Based on your comments you say you are having problems with global not being defined.

Searching Google this seems to be a solved issue, try:

> I think for now the best option would be to include
>
> `(window as any).global = window;`
>
> In your polyfills.ts file, as mentioned here:
>   [angular/angular-cli#9827 (comment)](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/678#issuecomment-389106098)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. now I'm not facing this fs problem after using this new WooCommerce API but, Now I get a new issue.
when I import this API my home page of Ionic app disappears. and when I comment this code it again reappears. Here is how I'm importing and using it. 
Code: http://prntscr.com/p8kc04
console Output : http://prntscr.com/p8kbmy

Comment: This is a new question about a new issue and a different library. I've updated my answer but normally you are supposed to start a new question in this scenario.

Comment: I have asked a new question here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039777/getting-blank-screen-after-importing-and-using-woocommerce-api) please look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to folder `\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js` and **replace** `node: false`, by `node: { crypto: true, stream: true, fs: "empty", net: "empty", tls: "empty" },`
It's working for me.