# Getting Blank screen after importing and using WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, ionic4, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to use WooCommerce API in Ionic4 application after importing API in my home page I cannot see anything on output screen below is code:
home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as WC from '@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

//Local Objet WooCommerce of type any
WooCommerce: any;

constructor() {

this.WooCommerce = WC({ 
   url: "https://shop.example.com",
   consumerKey: "ck_fc057c56e5b430c9f4be64c86225e11943647ca1",
   consumerSecret: "cs_12842c6e3c1122e9a17cb5c6b4e33aca3e0199528",
 });

 this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then( (data) => {
  console.log(data);
 }, (err) => {
  console.log(err)
 })
 }
 }
```

using this new WooCommerce API, and when I import this API my home page of Ionic app disappears. and when I comment this code it again reappears. Here is how I'm importing and using it.
after running this code I'm getting this on console Output:

https://prntscr.com/p8kbmy

Comment: I'm not sure how safe it is for you to be posting your `consumerSecret` in a public forum. I recommend that you regenerate these api keys for your site in case you have created a security issue.

Comment: Thank you, I had changed the key's before posting, now I have changed the website.
I'll remember not to mention keys from next time.
thank you for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, you are having problems with `global` not being defined.

The solution [seems to be](https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/1411#issuecomment-420818131) to define global yourself using this line:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

Open `/src/polyfills.ts` and add this to the bottom:

```
// BUG FIX: Add global to window, assigning the value of window itself.
// https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1166#issuecomment-386195105
(window as any).global = window;
```